# How would I show that time complexity function $T(n)=\frac{1}{2}n^2-\frac{1}{2}n$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

There is an algorithm which compares numbers in an array, and supposedly this time complexity function can be found from it. $n$ is the number of elements in the array.

I believe "show" is synonymous with "prove". But how can I prove this? I'm not particularly well versed in either, but am I supposed to use big O or proof by induction? Or something else entirely? I just do not know where I would start with this.

EDIT: Here is the algorithm. I'm sorry! I didn't know seeing the algorithm itself was essential finding out what kind of proof was needed.

Input $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $…$, $x_n$ ;
*check* := true ;
**while** *check* = true **do**
$\phantom{{}++{}}$**for** *i* := $1$ to $n-1$ **do**
$\phantom{{}++++{}}$**for** *j* := $i+1$ to $n$ **do**
$\phantom{{}++++++{}}$**if** $x_i = x_j$ **then**
$\phantom{{}++++++++{}}$*check* := false ;
Output *check* ;

Comment: Can you provide the pseudocode of the algorithm ? Anyway, I think the proof by induction is the best option you have, as you need an exact result, whereas big O would lead to have an approximation not taking into account constants, and only the biggest exponent.

Comment: Are you seriously asking us how to prove what the time complexity of an algorithm *you do not describe* is?

Comment: @5xum Yes, I'm sorry about that. I have added the algorithm now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about time complexity or this particular function, but my intuition tells me you want to do this by counting. So if $x_1,...,x_n$ are your numbers you must compare $x_1$ to $x_2,...,x_{n}$. Then you have to compare $x_2$ to $x_3,...,x_n$, $x_3$ to $x_4,...,x_n$, and finally $x_{n-1}$ to $x_n$. So you make $(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1$ comparisons, which is $(n-1)n/2$ total comparisons. You can figure that out the same way Gauss did.
\begin{align*}(n-1)&+(n-2)&+&...+&2\hspace{6mm}+&\hspace{6mm}1&=m\\1\hspace{6mm}&+\hspace{6mm}2&+&...+&(n-2)+&(n-1)&=m\\
n\hspace{6mm}&+\hspace{6mm}n&+&...+&n\hspace{6mm}+&\hspace{6mm}n&=2m
\end{align*}
$$m=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$